# UINavigationBar cut off font

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I'm using custom font in my application. I've used the code below in AppDelegate to change the UINavigationBar appearance.

```
let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 20)!]
```

However, the font is getting cut off at the end of the string. The text is "Tell", but you can see that the last character is getting cut off. It works fine if I'm using the default font. Is this a problem with the font itself or it's a bug in Xcode?

[image]

Comment: It is rather a missing feature than a "bug" in iOS. When you try to determine the size of an actual type it returns an incorrect text width suspectedly because the character "L" does not have a "node" on the right edge. One possible workaround to add a subview to your navigationbar and use a wider UILabel.